# Internet Explorer in the registry

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, registry

I was trying to inject a DLL in IE (scientific application, see: [CreateInstance() with detour DLL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613739/createinstance-with-detour-dll-injection))

But... I just give up as I think I found an easier way... see, what I need to do can be done in the prompt by:
withdll.exe /d:[DLL] [path\iexplore.exe]

(I already have the DLL)

All I need is that CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IWebBrowser2, [...] calls the above rather than simply [path\iexplore.exe] and I figure this should be somewhere in the registry.

Does anybody what key I should be looking at?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CreateInstance() with detour DLL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613739/createinstance-with-detour-dll-injection)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/20/9341164.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why there's a downvote. The [Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) registry key structure is formally documented.